# Python's multiprocessing returns more results than tasks where given

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to use multiprocessing for my simulation run, to evaluate different input values at the same time.

Therefore, I googled a lot in the last weeks and got something together which is probably not very pretty but it (somehow) works. My Problem is now, that it returns more output than I have given it tasks to do and I don't understand why.

Sometimes each simulation run returns only one value as expected but as in the example below I would expect the result of e.g. simulation run 5 to be only [23]. It also differs, which simulation run produces more output then expected. When I increase the number of periods to e.g. 2, it would generate 4 output values but I cannot figure out why that is.

Could please somebody give me a hint how I could change that? I cannot find an answer to that and I'm getting quite frustrated :(
Also any suggestions on how I could improve my code would be really appreciated as I'm quite new to python and I love it so far :)

This is the simplified code I use:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing
from itertools import repeat

class Simulation(Process):
    Nr = 1
    Mean = 5
    StdDev = 3
    Periods = 10
    Result = []

    def Generate_Value(self):
        GeneratedValue = max(int(round(np.random.normal(self.Mean, self.StdDev), 0)), 0)
        return GeneratedValue

    def runSimulation(self):
        for i in range(self.Periods):
            self.Result.append(self.Generate_Value())
        return self.Result

def worker(Mean, stdDev, Periods, Nr, queue):
    Sim = Simulation()
    Sim.Nr = Nr
    Sim.Periods = Periods
    Sim.Mean = Mean
    Sim.StdDev = stdDev
    Results = Sim.runSimulation()
    queue.put(Results)
    print("Simulation run " + str(Nr) + " done with a result of " + str(Results)
          + " (Input: mean: " + str(Mean) + ", std. dev.: " + str(stdDev) + ")")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = m.Queue()
    CPUS = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # CPUS = 8
    WORKERS = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPUS)

    Mean = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
    StdDev = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    Periods = 1
    Nr = list(range(1,len(Mean) + 1))

    WORKERS.starmap(worker, zip(Mean, StdDev, repeat(Periods), Nr, repeat(queue)))
    WORKERS.close()
    WORKERS.join()

    FinalSimulationResults = []
    for i in range(len(Mean)):
        FinalSimulationResults.append(queue.get())
    print(FinalSimulationResults)
```

Which results in e.g. this:

```
Simulation run 1 done with a result of [23] (Input: mean: 50, std. dev.: 10)
Simulation run 2 done with a result of [55] (Input: mean: 60, std. dev.: 10)
Simulation run 3 done with a result of [64] (Input: mean: 70, std. dev.: 10)
Simulation run 5 done with a result of [23, 89] (Input: mean: 90, std. dev.: 10)
Simulation run 4 done with a result of [78] (Input: mean: 80, std. dev.: 10)
[[23], [55], [64], [23, 89], [78]]
```

**It works now :)**. Not as fast as I expected (only 2 times faster with 8 cores) but for everyone who might has the same problem, here's my working code:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing
from itertools import repeat

class Simulation():
    def __init__(self, Nr, Mean, Std_dev, Periods):
        self.Result = []
        self.Nr = Nr
        self.Mean = Mean
        self.StdDev = Std_dev
        self.Periods = Periods

    def Generate_Value(self):
        GeneratedValue = max(int(round(np.random.normal(self.Mean, self.StdDev), 0)), 0)
        return GeneratedValue

    def runSimulation(self):
        for i in range(self.Periods):
            self.Result.append(self.Generate_Value())
        return self.Result

def worker(Mean, stdDev, Periods, Nr, queue):
    Sim = Simulation(Nr=Nr,Mean=Mean,Std_dev=stdDev,Periods=Periods)
    Results = Sim.runSimulation()
    queue.put(Results)
    print("Simulation run " + str(Nr) + " done with a result of " + str(Results)
          + " (Input: mean: " + str(Mean) + ", std. dev.: " + str(stdDev) + ")")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = m.Queue()
    CPUS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    WORKERS = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPUS)

    Mean = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
    StdDev = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    Periods = 100
    Nr = list(range(1,len(Mean) + 1))

    WORKERS.starmap(worker, zip(Mean, StdDev, repeat(Periods), Nr, repeat(queue)))
    WORKERS.close()
    WORKERS.join()

    FinalSimulationResults = []
    for i in range(len(Mean)):
        FinalSimulationResults.append(queue.get())

    print(FinalSimulationResults)
```

Comment: What value does CPUS have? I would guess that because the `Result` list is a class attribute somehow the attribute is leaking. You should put instance specific attribut into the `__init__` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you assign the attributes to the class makes the attributes class attributes. That way they are shared between every instance of the class. In your case this doesn't appear immideatly because in every process you only have one instance of the class and the class object itself is not shared between processes. Now if a worker is finished early enough that it can get another task the class object will be reused and the class attributes work "as expected".

To circumvent this you should always assign instance attributes (i.e. attributes that should be different from instance to instance) in the `__init__` function:

```
class Simulation(Process):

    def __init__(self, nr, mean, std_dev, periods):
        self.nr = nr
        self.mean = mean
        self.std_dev = std_dev
        self.periods = periods
        self.result = []

    def Generate_Value(self):
        GeneratedValue = max(int(round(np.random.normal(self.Mean, self.StdDev), 0)), 0)
        return GeneratedValue

    def runSimulation(self):
        for i in range(self.Periods):
            self.Result.append(self.Generate_Value())
        return self.Result
```

For further information see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

That said I don't think you should use the Process class in the way you are using it. `Pool` automatically handles Process creating for you and you only need to tell it what to do. So rewriting your code:

```
def task(nr, mean, std_dev, periods, results):
    for i in range(periods):
        results.append(max(int(round(np.random.normal(self.Mean, self.StdDev), 0)), 0))
    return results


m = multiprocessing.Manager()
queue = m.Queue()
cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # CPUS = 8
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPUS)

Mean = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
StdDev = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Periods = 1
Nr = list(range(1,len(Mean) + 1))

pool.starmap(task, zip(Mean, StdDev, repeat(Periods), Nr, repeat(queue)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

should work (not tested).

Comment: Great, thank you. That worked quite well. But I need to stick to the class solution. Of course in the example a simple function would be easier but in the real simulation I need the class as it is way more complex :)
Do you know why the speed only improved by the factor 2 and not 8?

Comment: I still think that the class should not inerhit from Process. Does it still work if you just remove the inheritance of Process? I guess it should. If the workload is too low the overhead of creating many processes can be higher than the gain. Do you still have an improvement of factor 2 if you have some "serios workload"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean that I should write class Simulation(): instead of class Simulation(Process): ?
In the real simulation I use about 5,000,000 periods and the 8 core version is about 2 - 3 times faster than the 1 core one.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. As far as I see you are not using "Simulation" as a process but just for your own logic. For the speedup I'm not quite sure. Do you use much Inter Process Communication (IPC)? That always slows stuff down. Or is the code you showed the "final code" that only runs 2 times faster?

Comment: I've done that and it still works. And yes, the code I've posted runs only 2 times faster. I have to implement the multiprocessing version into my simulation later on as this will take some time. What do you mean by I'm not using simulation as a process? I'm quite new to python and I'm not that familiar with classes. So if you have any improvement idea, I would be happy to hear it. I just wanted to have everything related to the simulation in one class

Comment: "Process" is a class which manages subprocesses, e.g. creating a new subprocess, closing subprocesses etc. Your class deals with the actions/code/task that should be executed in the process. If you would want to modify how processes are created you could subclass Process and overwrite some funcions, e.g. implement a own version of `run()` which does something with the arguments you provided. What you did has nothing to do with the process itself, so it does not need to inhertit from Process. Also I would follow [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) e.g. lowercase attributes.

Comment: If the code runs slower than expected maybe you are best off if you create a new question with a reproducable example. That way other people that know more about multiprocessing than be will se it and can answer.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. In my simulation I also overwrite the run function :)

Comment: Somehow, the function runSimulation(self) was previously just run(self) but I didn't figure out how I could return the results so I changed it to runSimulation(self). Could you please tell me how I could do that?

Comment: I thought it works the way it is now? Passing in the queue and adding to it seems fine to me. Otherwise use `return` to return something. Also the way you have overwritten `run` probably breaks the usage of the class Simulation as a process - just don't inherit from it.

Comment: Yes it does. I just thought from your comment that overwriting the run function would be more efficient :)